# How to convert non ascii characters to ascii characters for urls using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The characters will be used for website urls.
Characters must only contain a-z and 0-9.

I have tried to use [Normalize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.normalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) without success.

Example

/københavn > /koebenhavn
/köln > /koln
/k'ton > /kton
/привет > (missing)
/北京市 > (missing)

Comment: You could just URL encode the strings.

Comment: I want the URLs to be search engine optimized. CTR is higher for /koebenhavn than /kbenhavn.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want "transliteration" to basic latin (sometimes known as ASCII), specifically romanization.

A very comprehensive library would have to know every word or letter pattern in every script of every language. Most are not that ambitious and instead work in the context of a "letter" or two, applying the rules for one language to them all. You might need to patch the data, either the input or the output, to fine tune it.

NuGet package Unidecode.NET (and, for demo, MSTest.Framework).

```
Assert.AreNotEqual("koebenhavn",   "københavn".Unidecode());
Assert.AreEqual(   "kobenhavn",    "københavn".Unidecode());
Assert.AreEqual(   "koln",         "köln"     .Unidecode());
Assert.AreNotEqual("kton",         "k'ton"    .Unidecode());
Assert.AreEqual(   "k'ton",        "k'ton"    .Unidecode());
Assert.AreEqual(   "privet",       "привет"   .Unidecode());
Assert.AreEqual(   "Bei Jing Shi ","北京市"   .Unidecode());
```

Comment: I have to get the name for any word.

Almost working c# code.
path = item.Name;
path = path.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");
path = Utility.UnicodesToCharacter(path).ToLower();
path = Regex.Replace(path, "[^a-z0-9-]", string.Empty);